# How I can stream large data from mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, stream, mern, large-data

I got an issue when I use streams on my mern application, I have tried this code bellow  and I get back a response but it take along time about **40 seconds** to get all data.is there any solution ??

```
exports.getAllProduct=(req, res)=>{  

const cursor = Product.find().lean().cursor();

const products = [];
cursor.on("data", (doc) => {
products.push(doc);
 });
   cursor.on("error", (err) => {
console.error(err);
 });

cursor.on("end", () => {

res.json({
  data: {
    products,
  },
});
console.log("finished");
 });
 };
```

Comment: How many documents/how much data are you transferring? Does it all need to be returned to the client all at once? How fast are you expecting this to run?

Comment: I have  about  60 documents that contains images and lots of fields, it not need to be transferred at one, and user should be see data on products page after 10 seconds maximum